# REGEX To accept numbers separated by commas, but number range is 0-32767

Tags: regex, numbers, expression, range, spaces

I need to write a regular expression for taking input like this

```
23,456,22,1,32767
```

i.e.

1. No commas allowed at the start or end.
2. Spaces may come before and/or start of comma for e.g.  23, 45,56 ,67 etc.
3. Ranges of each number should be 0-32767.

Currently I am using regular expression like this `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*`.

This allows for numbers separated by commas only ( not allowing spaces at all), and it does not check for the range of number.

Comment: You don't want to check the number range with regex, it will be relay unreadable

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably wise to do it in two steps. First check that the range is 0-99999:

```
^[0-9]{1,5}( *, *[0-9]{1,5})*$
```

Then parse the string to a list of integers using a general purpose programming language and check that `x <= 32767` for each integer x.

Comment: +1, but you might want to add `\s*` around the comma to allow for spaces as Basmah asked.

Comment: "\s*" or " *"? The question seems very unclear on this point.

Comment: Thanks Mark ! This was of help!

Comment: Mark, would you please tell me the regex for th to write a regular expression for taking input like this

23,456,22,1,32767 i.e. 

1.No commas allowed at the start or end.
2.Spaces may come before and/or start of comma for e.g. 23, 45,56 ,67 etc.e following

Comment: what should I change in this just to accept numbers separated by commas and no spaces in between?

Comment: how to make them non repeating

Answer (score 9):

You *can* validate a number range with a regex, but since you need to look at the textual representation of numbers, the regex will be hard to read:

```
0*(?:3276[0-7]|327[0-5][0-9]|32[0-6][0-9]{2}|3[01][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])
```

matches an integer between 0 and 32767, with optional leading zeroes.

So your entire regex would be

```
^0*(?:3276[0-7]|327[0-5][0-9]|32[0-6][0-9]{2}|3[01][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])(?: *, *0*(?:3276[0-7]|327[0-5][0-9]|32[0-6][0-9]{2}|3[01][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]))*$
```

Now imagine you inherit that regex from a co-worker who has left your company years ago...Have fun :)

Therefore, take Mark's advice.

<sub>This answer is intended purely for educational purposes and does *not* constitute a recommendation to use a regex in this case.</sub>